# Запуск процесса от имени другого пользователя без знания пароля

Tags: c#

Есть Служба Windows, которая запускается под учётной записью "СИСТЕМА". Нужно как-то запустить программы (предположим 123.exe) не с учётной записью СИСТЕМА, а с учётной записью пользователя, который сейчас в системе.

Я нашёл такой пример:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\123.exe";
startInfo.Domain = "yourdomain"
startInfo.UserName = "yourusername"
startInfo.Password = pass;
Process.Start(Info);
```

К сожалению, **Пароля (startInfo.Password) я не знаю**, и запрашивать у пользователя каждый раз не очень удобно.

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c0ca087-5e7b-4046-93cb-c7b3e48d0dfb/how-run-client-application-as-a-windows-service-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral). Решение через WinAPI, основано на получении токена пользователя из активного приложения, запущенного от его имени. Пользователь обязан быть залогиненым в системе. Сам не проверял. Если это работает, то более простых вариантов нет.

Comment: @rdorn а разве права не переносятся автоматом, ну то есть, если пользователь запустил программу, а она в свою очередь запускает другую, то все права и пользовательское окружение ведь переносится из предыдущей, разве не так?

Comment: @Bulson именно так, но тут обходной хак, который возможен только для localSystem. ТС как раз и хочет, чтобы сервис из под системной учетки запустил процесс с правами текущего пользователя, а не системными.

Comment: @rdorn понял, спасибо

Comment: @rdorn Вроде работает, но я понял что из сервиса нельзя запускать программы с графическим интерфейсом, поэтому даже этот метод здесь отваливается (

Comment: По идее не должен падать, он же запускает программу в окружении пользователя. На выходных попробую если время будет. Мне кажется там можно поиграть параметрами окружения.

Comment: @rdorn Если я присоединяюсь к процессу сервиса через отладку Visual Studio и прогоняю метод с отладкой, то всё работает; если без отладки - то нет. Причём, до старта программы метод (там кроме старта ещё пара действий) доходит (процесс убивается, это видно в диспетчере задач)

Comment: Все равно интересно посмотреть руками

Comment: @rdorn Вру. Метод работает идеально. Это я сморозил чушь - у меня метод обваливался с UnauthorizedAccessException когда я файл пытался удалить...

Comment: Можете оформить как ответ, только не забудьте автора и ссылку на оригиналный текст указать. Или сам позже оформлю.

Comment: @Arasfon не могли бы Вы показать, какой вид имеет командная строка, которую надо передать в метод `Lauch()`?