# Отправить Form.Message.Box() активному пользователю

Tags: c#, form

Можно ли отправить форму с сообщением от одного пользователя другому?

```
// подготовка к обновлению, копирование файлов из сетевой шары на локальный ПК и т.д. 
Form.Message.Box(); // сообщение для активного пользователя, не готов ли он обновиться с выбором ответа 
//если готов, то обновление: закрытие программы, замена ранее скопированных файлов и т.д.
```

Если конкретнее, ситуация такова. Написал программку, чтобы не ставить в ручную хотфиксы на работе для 90+ юзверей. Если запускать руками, самому(от админской учетки в системе), все работает идеально, но не могу прикрутить удаленную установку.

получается что программа, при удаленной установке, запускается от имени "система" и конечно пользователь "%USER_NAME%" не видит "Form.Message.Box();"

Не могу прикрутить к программе, чтобы она запускалась от одного пользователя, и спрашивала у активного(который залогинился и сидит работает) разрешения на установку. просто насильно закрыть и обновить нельзя, дверь не запирается, придут в кабинет и поколотят.
Если такая вообще возможность в c#? Не обязательно прям готовое решение дать, напишите, если кто знает, хотя бы в какую сторону копать.

Пробовал прикручивать

```
DialogResult resualt = MessageBox.Show("Произвести обновление сейчас?", "install hotfix", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
 
/*MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly так же пробовал менять на 
 *MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification 
/*Результат отрицательный, прога схлопывается как только доходит до формы с выбором ответа.
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что программа, для которой устанавливаются хотфиксы - не ваша? Вы написали отдельную программку, которая никак не связана с обновляемой? Как вариант, можно добавить вашу программку в автозапуск юзерам, и пусть она висит в трее, без основного окна. А когда появились обновления, пусть скачивает их, подготавливает и потом отображает юзеру диалог с предложением обновиться.

Comment: Правильно, программа не моя. Не совсем удобный вариант, так неудобно будет следить у кого и как выполнилось, распространяю через Kaspersky Security Centrе. Для меня основной вопрос, можно ли отправить запрос от одного пользователя другому. чтото всю голову сломал. по аналогии работает в "cmd.exe" утилита "MSG"(пример "msg user "Какой то текст" ").

Comment: Если вы можете с помощью KSC запускать свою программу из под пользователя с правами администратора, то используйте "msg", например: Process.Start(GetMsgPath(), "* \"Необходимо перезагрузиться!\""); Здесь метод GetMsgPath() должен возвращать путь до утилиты MSG нужной версии (x64 или x86, зависит от версии Windows). Например, Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\system32\msg.exe" или Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\sysnative\msg.exe").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел классный ответ [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c0ca087-5e7b-4046-93cb-c7b3e48d0dfb/how-run-client-application-as-a-windows-service-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral), парень подкидывает токен от активного пользователя. попробовал и работает. Кому надо будет нечто похожее, рекомендую.

Кстати ранее обсуждалось на форуме уже с ответом. [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886416/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]